# Is it possiblie to deploy my custom Deep learning model to android/ios with the help of ML Kit? If yes How?

Tags: deep-learning, google-mlkit

Simply put, I think, google ML kit is just awesome. I can not understand how Google manages to put together these awesome APIs and then let them use for no cost to developers.

That being said, the requirements I have are not being covered in exiting API, so it is possible to deploy a set of (pipeline of) my custom deep learning models to edge devices using ML kit?

If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ML Kit's [Image Labeling](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/image-labeling) and [Object Detection & Tracking](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection) APIs offer support for [custom image classification models](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models). If you want something beyond that, you can check out [g.co/on-device-ml](http://g.co/on-device-ml) to find out more suitable on-device ML solutions.